# Names of different sharepoint release

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am new to sharepoint and little confused with the name of different releases.

Different releases what I found on internet are

1. Microsoft sharepoint service 3.0 (popular as MSS 3.0)
2. Microsoft office sharepoint server 2007 (popular as MOSS 2007)
3. latest is Microsoft Sharepoint server 2010

Is these names correct? When some one talks about MOSS then may be its the 2007 version isn't it?
Why the name of 2010 release is not MOSS 2010?
Sorry but little confused. Can someone clarify this?
However I am aware between the difference in 3.0 and 2007. But names are confusing.

Comment: oh btw, i bet you can find it on google by typing "SharePoint Versions", I wondering how yu gonna work on SharePoint if you dont know how to google :) lol

Comment: I do not believe tropicaljava is asking about the history of SharePoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct names are:

1. Microsoft Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 (AKA WSS 3.0)
2. Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007 (AKA MOSS 2007)
3. Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (AKA SPS 2010)

Yes, when someone mentions MOSS they are are referring to MOSS 2007.

Microsoft decided to rename the product name.

WSS 3.0 is replaced by Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 (AKA SPF 2010)
MOSS 2007 is replaced by SPS 2010

Comment: Thanks, Is it right that MOSS 2007 bundles with MS office? However SPS 2010 doesn't have MS office included. Further, this SPF 2010 is new addition to my list. what's difference in SPF2010 and SPS2010? Sorry for many question but last one please, so there is nothing like Sharepoint server 2007 its just MOSS 2007, right?

Comment: Do you mean SPS2010 is build on top of SPF2010? Seems a typo in your answer.

Comment: No, MOSS 2007 product is not bundled with MS Office product. Just like how MOSS is build on top of WSS 3.0, SPS 2010 is build on top of SPF 2010. All the features in SPF are included in SPS. SPF is free. SPS is not free. SPS adds more capabilities to SharePoint, such as Enterprise Search, Social Data and User Profiles, Enterprise Content Management, Web Content Management, Analytics, Word Automation Services, Access Services, Visio Services, PerformancePoint Services, Excel Services, Dashboards, InfoPath Forms Services.

Answer (score 6):

[image: SharePoint Versions - a history]

From http://blog.pentalogic.net/2010/06/sharepoint-versions-history/

Comment: You should add SharePoint 2013 :)

Comment: We don't yet officially know that's what it will be called. Probably, but not yet official.